# Swift 2 JSON POST request [dictionary vs. String for HTTPBody of NSMutableURLRequest]

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift2, nsurlsession

I have the following swift code that submits a `POST` request successfully.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = "foo=bar&baz=lee".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

Instead of using query parameter like syntax, I'd like to use a dictionary, but when I do the following:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["foo":"bar", "lee":"baz"], options: [])

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

(like what I've seen around), it seems to submits the request as if the body is empty.

My main question is: how do these syntaxes differ, and how do the resulting requests differ?

*NOTE*: Coming from JS, I'm testing the endpoint in a javascript environment (jquery.com's console) like the following, and it's working successfully:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'lee'
  }
});
```

Comment: x-www-form-urlencoded vs application/json.  you haven't set the Content-Type header field to application/json.

Comment: Omfg, I actually spent three hours trying to figure this s**T out... one method wasn't working and it was because i ommited this too.. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @mrkbxt said. It's not a matter of how the syntax differs, but a matter of the different data types your sending with your request. UTF8 string encoded text is the default value for `NSMutableURLRequest` content type, which is why your first request works. To use a JSON in the body you have to switch the content type to use JSON.

Add the following to your request object so it accepts JSON:

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that, but it didn't change anything.  If I look at the request in the JS example, it is also `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so perhaps jquery is doing some conversion from a js object to UTF8 string encoded text if you don't specify a content type... my server might not accept json at all... I'll report back.

Comment: Yup that was it, I was looking at the wrong part of the request.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

For a content-Type of type "x-www-form-urlencoded" you can do the following.

```
 let bodyParameter = ["foo":"bar", "lee":"baz"]
 let bodyString = bodyData.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&")
 let encodedData = NSMutableData(data: bodyString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 request.HTTPBody
 request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

This will take your dictionary, tranform it into a string that conforms to the content-Type of your request (by joining the dictionary using a separator) and then encoding it using utf8.