# JSON query with SWIFT, iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, json, swift, api

I would like to convert this query in swift :

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax(
{
    url: "http://website.net/api/Clients/",
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {"Token": "Votre token"},
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "PhoneNumber": phoneNumberValue, "SecretCode":      secretCodeValue },
    success: function (data) { alert("it worked!") }
});
<script>
```

I tried this in Swift without success :

```
func submitNumber() {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://website.net/api/Clients/")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST”
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Token" : “myKey”]
        let requestDictionary = ["PhoneNumber": 3333333333, "SecretCode": 12345]

        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestDictionary, options: [])

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                do {
                  let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                    print(json)

                    }catch {
                        print(error)
                }


            } else {
                print(“failure”)
                }
            }
                    }
        task.resume()
    }
```

But it is always printed "failure", I have no idea oh how to handle it...

How can I do it, please? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704965/swift-2-json-post-request-dictionary-vs-string-for-httpbody-of-nsmutableurlreq/36705866?noredirect=1#comment61138687_36705866z) question. Your not setting your request's content-type to accept json.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of another question, then you should *flag it as duplicate* instead of posting an answer which is just a link to the other answer. Thank you.

Comment: The question is different but the line of code he needs is the same.

Comment: Flagging the question as duplicate also applies in this case.

Comment: Hi @NSGangster, thanks for the answer, I add it, I still get an error 400. Do you see what could be still wrong ?

Comment: @L.Valentin likely your request url is not valid or the server is down.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is a list of http status codes that can help you debug what happens with your errors.